# How to reproduce this Feynman diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-feynman

I want to reproduce the following diagram
[image]

and here's my code (I'm using `tikz` to draw an ellipse for the loop overlayed with bent arrows):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{bending, ext.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b.base)]
    \begin{feynman}[/tikz/rect/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=.1cm, fill=white}]
        \vertex (a);
        \begin{scope}[shift={(3.075,-0.575)}, rotate=-45]
            \draw (0,0) coordinate (center) ellipse (0.775cm and 0.4cm);
            \foreach \sa in {0, 180}
            \foreach \da in {120, -120}
            \path[-{Centered Triangle[scale length=2, bend]}, tips]
            (\sa:1) arc[start angle=\sa, delta angle=\da, x radius=0.775cm, y radius=0.4cm];
            \node[dot, label=90:\(P_{lin}\)] (g) at (0,0.4);
            \node[dot, label=-90:\(P_{lin}\)] (h) at (0,-0.4);
        \end{scope}
        \node[rect, label=90:\(F_3\)] (b) at (2.5, 0);
        \node[dot,label=120:\(P_{lin}\)] (c) at (3.5,1);
        \node[rect, label=-90:\(F_2\)] (d) at (3.65, -1.15);
        \vertex (e) at (4.5,2);
        \vertex (f) at (4.5,-2);
        \diagram*{(b) -- [fermion] (a), (c) -- [fermion] (b), (c) -- [fermion] (e), (d) -- [fermion] (f)};
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that the arrows are not overlayed correctly. However, if I set `x radius=1cm` then the arrows appear as expected, but now the ellipse is not of desired size. Here's the code for this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{bending, ext.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b.base)]
    \begin{feynman}[/tikz/rect/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=.1cm, fill=white}]
        \vertex (a);
        \begin{scope}[shift={(3.075,-0.575)}, rotate=-45]
            \draw (0,0) coordinate (center) ellipse (1cm and 0.4cm);
            \foreach \sa in {0, 180}
            \foreach \da in {120, -120}
            \path[-{Centered Triangle[scale length=2, bend]}, tips]
            (\sa:1) arc[start angle=\sa, delta angle=\da, x radius=1cm, y radius=0.4cm];
            \node[dot, label=90:\(P_{lin}\)] (g) at (0,0.4);
            \node[dot, label=-90:\(P_{lin}\)] (h) at (0,-0.4);
        \end{scope}
        \node[rect, label=90:\(F_3\)] (b) at (2.5, 0);
        \node[dot,label=120:\(P_{lin}\)] (c) at (3.5,1);
        \node[rect, label=-90:\(F_2\)] (d) at (3.65, -1.15);
        \vertex (e) at (4.5,2);
        \vertex (f) at (4.5,-2);
        \diagram*{(b) -- [fermion] (a), (c) -- [fermion] (b), (c) -- [fermion] (e), (d) -- [fermion] (f)};
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You're using the radius 1 in the coordinate for the start of the arc but you need to use the same radii as for your arc: `(\sa:.775 and .4)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `(\sa:1)` as your starting point for your arc but you must use the same radii for this polar coordinate

```
\draw (0,0) ellipse (0.775 and 0.4);
\foreach \sa in {0, 180}
  \foreach \da in {120, -120}
    \path[-{Centered Triangle[scale length=2, bend]}, tips]
       (\sa:.775 and .4) arc[start angle=\sa, delta angle=\da,
                             x radius=0.775, y radius=0.4];
```

I've also removed the `cm`s so as not to mix coordinates of the *xyz* and the canvas coordinate system.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{bending, ext.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b.base)]
\begin{feynman}[/tikz/rect/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=.1cm, fill=white}]
\vertex (a);
\begin{scope}[shift={(3.075,-0.575)}, rotate=-45]
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (0.775 and 0.4);
  \foreach \sa in {0, 180}
    \foreach \da in {120, -120}
      \path[-{Centered Triangle[scale length=2, bend]}, tips]
         (\sa:.775 and .4) arc[start angle=\sa, delta angle=\da,
                               x radius=0.775, y radius=0.4];
  \node[dot, label= 90:\(P_{lin}\)] (g) at (0,0.4);
  \node[dot, label=-90:\(P_{lin}\)] (h) at (0,-0.4);
\end{scope}
\node[rect, label= 90:\(F_3\)] (b) at (2.5, 0);
\node[rect, label=-90:\(F_2\)] (d) at (3.65, -1.15);
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

That said, I believe it is time to use a more automatic way to place arrow tips. The following uses a specialised `softpath arrow` pic that uses PGF's internal softpath to draw bended arrow tips partially along curves (and also straight lines).

While TikZ-Feynman already brings its `anti majorana` key that one places once again `isosceles triangle` nodes along the path and not arrow tips which is where the `anti majorana'` key comes in which uses aforementioned pic.

The black dots with *P*<sub>lin</sub> annoted will also be placed along the edges via the `middle dot` key, the annotation is a label on that dot.

Instead of an ellipse a curved path is used directly between the vertices.

This ought to be a much more natural way to specify these diagrams.

---

*Note:* It would probably best to replace some internal of TikZ-Feynman to give a consistent output in regards to the triangles and sizes and keys and all but that will need some digging through the source.

The `middle dot` and `rect` keys are defines as they would be according to the unwritten TikZ-Feynman rulebook.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{bending, ext.arrows, quotes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  pos </.initial=0,
  pics/softpath arrow/.style={% does work well for curves and -- lines
    foreground code=, background code=,
    setup code=\pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath\tikz@temp
      \pgfprocesssplitsubpath\tikz@temp\expandafter\pgf@parse@end
      \pgfprocessresultsubpathsuffix\pgf@stop\pgf@stop\pgf@stop,
    code=\pgfset{tips}\pgfsetarrows{#1}\pgftransformreset
      \ifx\pgfpointthirdlastonpath\relax % it's a line
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointlineattime{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pos <}}
            {\pgfpointsecondlastonpath}{\pgfpointlastonpath}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointlineattime
          {\tikz@time}{\pgfpointsecondlastonpath}{\pgfpointlastonpath}}%
      \else
        \pgfpathcurvebetweentime{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pos <}}{\tikz@time}
          {\pgfpointfourthlastonpath}{\pgfpointthirdlastonpath}
          {\pgfpointsecondlastonpath}{\pgfpointlastonpath}%
      \fi
      \pgfusepath{}}}
\makeatother
\tikzfeynmanset{
  Feynman Triangle/.tip={Centered Triangle[scale length=2, bend]},
  middle dot/.style={/tikz/edge node={node[/tikzfeynman/every middle dot@@,#1]{}}},
  every middle dot/.style={/tikzfeynman/every middle dot@@/.append style={#1}},
  every middle dot@@/.style={shape=circle, fill, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+5pt},
  rect/.style={/tikzfeynman/every rect@@},
  every rect@@/.style={/tikz/shape=rectangle, /tikz/draw, /pgf/minimum size=.1cm},
  every rect/.style={/tikzfeynman/every rect@@/.append style={#1}},
  anti majorana'/.style args={#1:#2}{
    /tikz/edge node={pic[pos <=#1, pos=#2]{
      softpath arrow=Feynman Triangle-Feynman Triangle}}},
  anti majorana'/.default={.25:.75}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b.base), bend angle=60, semithick]
\newcommand*\Plin{\(P_{\mathrm{lin}}\)} % that seems to come up more than once
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a);
\vertex[rect, "\(F_3\)"      ] (b) at (2.5 ,  0   ) {}; % use \vertex … {} here
\vertex[rect, "\(F_2\)" below] (d) at (3.65, -1.15) {}; % use \vertex … {} here
\vertex (e) at (4.5,  2);
\vertex (f) at (4.5, -2);
\diagram*[use existing nodes, /tikz/every label/.append style={inner sep=+.15em}]{
  b -- [fermion] a,
  b -- [middle dot="\Plin" above left, anti majorana'] e,
  d -- [fermion] f,
  b --[bend left, middle dot="\Plin" above right, anti majorana'] d
    --[bend left, middle dot="\Plin" below  left, anti majorana'] b
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: We could have used the `Circle` tip to also have a bended circle but that seems silly.